# JMeter extract all values from regular expression and store in a csv

Tags: groovy, jmeter, beanshell

I am trying to extract all extracted values from regular expression extractor from multiple regular expressions and store it in a csv format.

I have tried for each controller after each extraction of values, how ever controller allows only one variable at a time. I would need to extract multiple variables in a single csv as part of data preparation and input to an another script. Any idea how can i achieve this requirement. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add [JSR223 PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) **after** the Regular Expression Extractor
2. Put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   def csv = new File("my.csv")
   1.upto(vars.get("foo_matchNr") as int, {
       csv << vars.get("foo_$it") << System.getProperty("line.separator")  
   })
   ```
3. Replate `my.csv` with the desired name of the CSV file and `foo` with the reference name of the variable defined in the Regular Expression Extractor
4. Once you run your script you will see a new CSV file in JMeter's "bin" folder containing values from the Regular Expression Extractor, each value on a new line

   [image: JMeter Write Values from Extractor to CSV file]

More information:

- [Groovy Looping Structures](http://groovy-lang.org/semantics.html#_looping_structures)
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)

Comment: Thanks Dmitri for your prompt response. Solution you provided worked well if we have one variable. Could you please help me in extending the code you provided to extract multiple variables i.e from a response containing multiple regex defined with a comma separated. Thanks

Comment: You cannot have more than one variable originating from a single Regular Expression Extractor. If you have 2 extractors you can go for something like `csv << vars.get("var1_$it") << "," << vars.get("var2_$it") << "," << vars.get("var3_$it") << System.getProperty("line.separator")`

Comment: Thanks, please see the code below i have used. I undestood the logic of printing the variables to the file. I need help in the extracting the values of second variable (from the 2nd line of the code). def csv = new File("my.csv")
1.upto(vars.get("var1_matchNr") (vars.get("var2_matchNr")) as int, {
    csv << vars.get("var1_$it") << "," << vars.get("var2_$it") << System.getProperty("line.separator")

Comment: I have used two regular expression extraction and trying to print the returned values of the array into a CSV. I am not much familar with groovy not sure how the second variable can be initialize into the upto method.

Comment: @DmitriT This only works if stored variable is of datatype ***int***. What do you do when you have String ?

Answer (score 0):

In regular expression extractor use "Match No." as -1 to get multiple values. Then use each controller to get the values like Eachvariable_1, Eachvariable_2 etc. Alternatively, you can fetch the values directly like var_1, var_2. Here, var is the name of the regular expression created variable.

Then, use JSR223 post processor and write the extracted values in the csv.
Hope this helps.

Also, note the below point if you are using For Each Controller:-

> JMeter will expose the looping index as a variable named **jm**__idx. So for example, if your Loop Controller is
>   named FEC, then you can access the looping index through
>   ${__jm__FEC__idx}. Index starts at 0

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response. using for each controller I would need to create multiple controllers for each regular expression as controller do not accept more than one variable in input variable index , I am looking for a solution where it can be done through programatically by storing the returned values into an array and print them to csv using comma for each variable in one single file as I have more than 15 variables to be captured.