# Using JMeter, how can I extract a string from the body of a response of an API and save it to a csv file?

Tags: groovy, jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing, beanshell

I am getting some different body responses from an API which look something like this :

"eyJhbRciOiRRRzI1RiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2RybmRtZSI6IlRlcmhhdCIsInR1aWQiOiJRZXJoYXQiLRJyb2xlRjoibW9iaWxlRRRwcCIsImVtYWlsIjoidGVzdEB0ZXN0LmNvbSIsImlkIjoiU2RyaGF0IiwiaWR0IjoxRRR5MDU5OTUxLCJleRRiOjE1NRkwNzQzRRR9.RRzm3VvioZ_iR-v5EGSSfYJLf0d9aZ-9R-RP4UbER04"

I am extracting it using JMeter's Regular Expression Extractor, like this:
[image]

**How can I print the values from the Regular Expression Extractor to a .csv file for later use in a different test?**

I tried the solution presented here, but it did not help. Maybe that script requires more tweaking, but i have no groovy knowledge:
[JMeter extract all values from regular expression and store in a csv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51284957/jmeter-extract-all-values-from-regular-expression-and-store-in-a-csv)

I would greatly appreciate any help you can offer.

**Updated question:** 
Using the exact code from the answer of the previously mentioned question, I'd get the bellow error:

Code:

```
def csv = new File("my.csv")
1.upto(vars.get("foo_matchNr") as int, {
    csv << vars.get("foo_$it") << System.getProperty("line.separator")  
})
```

Error:

```
    019-02-02 11:30:26,972 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Running the test!
2019-02-02 11:30:26,974 INFO o.a.j.s.SampleEvent: List of sample_variables: []
2019-02-02 11:30:26,978 INFO o.a.j.g.u.JMeterMenuBar: setRunning(true, *local*)
2019-02-02 11:30:27,223 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Starting ThreadGroup: 1 : Thread Group
2019-02-02 11:30:27,223 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Starting 3 threads for group Thread Group.
2019-02-02 11:30:27,223 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Thread will continue on error
2019-02-02 11:30:27,224 INFO o.a.j.t.ThreadGroup: Starting thread group... number=1 threads=3 ramp-up=1 perThread=333.33334 delayedStart=false
2019-02-02 11:30:27,226 INFO o.a.j.t.ThreadGroup: Started thread group number 1
2019-02-02 11:30:27,225 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread started: Thread Group 1-1
2019-02-02 11:30:27,226 INFO o.a.j.s.FileServer: Stored: D:/Software/apache-jmeter-5.0/bin/testUser.csv
2019-02-02 11:30:27,226 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: All thread groups have been started
2019-02-02 11:30:27,559 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread started: Thread Group 1-2
2019-02-02 11:30:27,892 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread started: Thread Group 1-3
2019-02-02 11:30:28,428 ERROR o.a.j.e.JSR223PostProcessor: Problem in JSR223 script, JSR223 PostProcessor
javax.script.ScriptException: org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.GroovyCastException: Cannot cast object 'null' with class 'null' to class 'int'. Try 'java.lang.Integer' instead
    at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScriptEngineImpl.eval(GroovyScriptEngineImpl.java:324) ~[groovy-all-2.4.15.jar:2.4.15]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyCompiledScript.eval(GroovyCompiledScript.java:72) ~[groovy-all-2.4.15.jar:2.4.15]
    at javax.script.CompiledScript.eval(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
    at org.apache.jmeter.util.JSR223TestElement.processFileOrScript(JSR223TestElement.java:221) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.0 r1840935]
    at org.apache.jmeter.extractor.JSR223PostProcessor.process(JSR223PostProcessor.java:44) [ApacheJMeter_components.jar:5.0 r1840935]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.runPostProcessors(JMeterThread.java:925) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.0 r1840935]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:564) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.0 r1840935]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:486) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.0 r1840935]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:253) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.0 r1840935]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_191]
Caused by: org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.GroovyCastException: Cannot cast object 'null' with class 'null' to class 'int'. Try 'java.lang.Integer' instead
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.DefaultTypeTransformation.castToNumber(DefaultTypeTransformation.java:176) ~[groovy-all-2.4.15.jar:2.4.15]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.DefaultTypeTransformation.intUnbox(DefaultTypeTransformation.java:82) ~[groovy-all-2.4.15.jar:2.4.15]
    at Script5.run(Script5.groovy:2) ~[?:?]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScriptEngineImpl.eval(GroovyScriptEngineImpl.java:321) ~[groovy-all-2.4.15.jar:2.4.15]
    ... 9 more
2019-02-02 11:30:28,436 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread is done: Thread Group 1-1
2019-02-02 11:30:28,439 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread finished: Thread Group 1-1
2019-02-02 11:30:28,583 ERROR o.a.j.e.JSR223PostProcessor: Problem in JSR223 script, JSR223 PostProcessor
javax.script.ScriptException: org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.GroovyCastException: Cannot cast object 'null' with class 'null' to class 'int'. Try 'java.lang.Integer' instead
    at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScriptEngineImpl.eval(GroovyScriptEngineImpl.java:324) ~[groovy-all-2.4.15.jar:2.4.15]
```

etc.

Plus 2 more errors like that.

I think that "foo_matchNr" is seen as one variable and just "foo" is my variable which changes it's value everytime or it's a list of values? I don't know how this Regular Expression Extractor works or groovy for that matter.

Using the code adapted (using my 0 level knowledge of groovy code) from the answer of the previously mentioned question, I'd get the bellow error:

Changed code:

```
def csv = new File("my.csv")
1.upto(vars.get("foo") as int, {
    csv << vars.get("foo_$it") << System.getProperty("line.separator")  
})
```

Error:

```
2019-02-02 11:08:27,613 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Running the test!
2019-02-02 11:08:27,614 INFO o.a.j.s.SampleEvent: List of sample_variables: []
2019-02-02 11:08:27,635 INFO o.a.j.g.u.JMeterMenuBar: setRunning(true, *local*)
2019-02-02 11:08:27,850 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Starting ThreadGroup: 1 : Thread Group
2019-02-02 11:08:27,850 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Starting 3 threads for group Thread Group.
2019-02-02 11:08:27,850 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Thread will continue on error
2019-02-02 11:08:27,850 INFO o.a.j.t.ThreadGroup: Starting thread group... number=1 threads=3 ramp-up=1 perThread=333.33334 delayedStart=false
2019-02-02 11:08:27,851 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread started: Thread Group 1-1
2019-02-02 11:08:27,852 INFO o.a.j.s.FileServer: Stored: D:/Software/apache-jmeter-5.0/bin/testUser.csv
2019-02-02 11:08:27,853 INFO o.a.j.t.ThreadGroup: Started thread group number 1
2019-02-02 11:08:27,853 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: All thread groups have been started
2019-02-02 11:08:28,187 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread started: Thread Group 1-2
2019-02-02 11:08:28,520 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread started: Thread Group 1-3
2019-02-02 11:08:28,794 ERROR o.a.j.e.JSR223PostProcessor: Problem in JSR223 script, JSR223 PostProcessor
javax.script.ScriptException: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "eyJhbRciOiRRRzI1RiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2RybmRtZSI6IlRlcmhhdCIsInR1aWQiOiJRZXJoYXQiLRJyb2xlRjoibW9iaWxlRRRwcCIsImVtYWlsIjoidGVzdEB0ZXN0LmNvbSIsImlkIjoiU2RyaGF0IiwiaWR0IjoxRRR5MDU5OTUxLCJleRRiOjE1NRkwNzQzRRR9.RRzm3VvioZ_iR-v5EGSSfYJLf0d9aZ-9R-RP4UbER04"
    at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScriptEngineImpl.eval(GroovyScriptEngineImpl.java:324) ~[groovy-all-2.4.15.jar:2.4.15]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyCompiledScript.eval(GroovyCompiledScript.java:72) ~[groovy-all-2.4.15.jar:2.4.15]
    at javax.script.CompiledScript.eval(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
    at org.apache.jmeter.util.JSR223TestElement.processFileOrScript(JSR223TestElement.java:221) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.0 r1840935]
    at org.apache.jmeter.extractor.JSR223PostProcessor.process(JSR223PostProcessor.java:44) [ApacheJMeter_components.jar:5.0 r1840935]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.runPostProcessors(JMeterThread.java:925) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.0 r1840935]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:564) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.0 r1840935]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:486) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.0 r1840935]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:253) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.0 r1840935]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_191]
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "eyJhbRciOiRRRzI1RiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2RybmRtZSI6IlRlcmhhdCIsInR1aWQiOiJRZXJoYXQiLRJyb2xlRjoibW9iaWxlRRRwcCIsImVtYWlsIjoidGVzdEB0ZXN0LmNvbSIsImlkIjoiU2RyaGF0IiwiaWR0IjoxRRR5MDU5OTUxLCJleRRiOjE1NRkwNzQzRRR9.RRzm3VvioZ_iR-v5EGSSfYJLf0d9aZ-9R-RP4UbER04"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
    at java.lang.Integer.valueOf(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.StringGroovyMethods.toInteger(StringGroovyMethods.java:3319) ~[groovy-all-2.4.15.jar:2.4.15]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.StringGroovyMethods.asType(StringGroovyMethods.java:178) ~[groovy-all-2.4.15.jar:2.4.15]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.dgm$1048.doMethodInvoke(Unknown Source) ~[groovy-all-2.4.15.jar:2.4.15]
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1225) ~[groovy-all-2.4.15.jar:2.4.15]
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1034) ~[groovy-all-2.4.15.jar:2.4.15]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.invokePojoMethod(InvokerHelper.java:935) ~[groovy-all-2.4.15.jar:2.4.15]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.invokeMethod(InvokerHelper.java:926) ~[groovy-all-2.4.15.jar:2.4.15]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodN(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:181) ~[groovy-all-2.4.15.jar:2.4.15]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.asType(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:604) ~[groovy-all-2.4.15.jar:2.4.15]
    at Script4.run(Script4.groovy:2) ~[?:?]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScriptEngineImpl.eval(GroovyScriptEngineImpl.java:321) ~[groovy-all-2.4.15.jar:2.4.15]
    ... 9 more
2019-02-02 11:08:28,797 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread is done: Thread Group 1-1
2019-02-02 11:08:28,797 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread finished: Thread Group 1-1
2019-02-02 11:08:29,160 ERROR o.a.j.e.JSR223PostProcessor: Problem in JSR223 script, JSR223 PostProcessor
javax.script.ScriptException: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "
```

This time it "sees" the strings I am interested in processing, but it seems to encounter some issues processing them.
I get 2 more errors like that for the other 2 variables that I get from the other 2 responses which contain different strings (I am making 3 requests and getting 3 responses, each containing different body strings). Just the value after the "For input string" is different.

Comment: What error did you get in JMeter log?

Comment: @ Vadim Yangunaev  I updated the question with the groovy code I tried and the errors I got + my simple-minded observations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have only one match in your responce use this code to paste into JSR223 PostProcessor:

```
def csv = new File("my.csv")
csv << vars.get("foo") << System.getProperty("line.separator")
```

Comment: Thanks for showing interest in my issue! Your solution works, but it does not separate the different strings on separate rows. It doesn't separate them at all. Any Idea how I could achieve that?

Comment: I figured out how to place the strings on a new line in the csv file by combining your answer with the previous code I played with: def csv = new File("my.csv")
csv << vars.get("foo") << System.getProperty("line.separator")   ; I would suggest you add this to your answer and I will mark it as a solution. Also, a great help for me would be if you could add the code that overrides the .csv file if it exists or creates a new one with incremental naming. Currently, if the file exists, it will not make any action.

Comment: @JustNatural I've updated the answer's code according your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

1. For your first piece of "code"

   ```
   def csv = new File("my.csv")
   1.upto(vars.get("foo_matchNr") as int, {
       csv << vars.get("foo_$it") << System.getProperty("line.separator")  
   })
   ```

   the error is telling `${foo_matchNr}` variable does not exist, double check that it is present and has a numeric value using [Debug Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler) and [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener combination.
2. For your second piece of code:

   ```
   def csv = new File("my.csv")
   1.upto(vars.get("foo") as int, {
       csv << vars.get("foo_$it") << System.getProperty("line.separator")  
   })
   ```

   the error is telling that it cannot cast this line:

   ```
      eyJhbRciOiRRRzI1RiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2RybmRtZSI6IlRlcmhhdCIsInR1aWQiOiJRZXJoYXQiLRJyb2xlRjoibW9iaWxlRRRwcCIsImVtYWlsIjoidGVzdEB0ZXN0LmNvbSIsImlkIjoiU2RyaGF0IiwiaWR0IjoxRRR5MDU5OTUxLCJleRRiOjE1NRkwNzQzRRR9.RRzm3VvioZ_iR-v5EGSSfYJLf0d9aZ-9R-RP4UbER04
   ```

   to an [Integer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html). My expectation is that you need to change the code to something like:

   ```
   new File("my.csv") << vars.get("foo") << System.getProperty("line.separator")
   ```

If the above code will not produce what you're looking for - update your question with the output of the aforementioned Debug Sampler and indicate which variable(s) you would like to store and how.

Check out [The Groovy Templates Cheat Sheet for JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-groovy-templates-cheat-sheet-for-jmeter) article to get started with Groovy scripting.

---

In general I would  recommend using [Sample Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html#sample_variables) property in order to store generated JMeter variables into the .jtl results file. If you want the output to go into a separate file - consider using [Flexible File Writer](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/FlexibleFileWriter/)